# Handling the 'back' button after performing sub-routines on android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm wondering how to handle sub processes with the back button in mind.

For example:

1. Skipping the login screen when clicking back from the default view
2. Pre-upload processing view. I want the back button to return to the last activity before the upload after the user uploaded or canceled.

I imagine the solution will include overriding the finish() behavior, I'm just not sure about the details.

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a previous Activity from appearing when the user uses the back button you should use the [`noHistory`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) manifest flag.

I suggest you read up on how the Activity backstack works in more detail. This guide should prove useful:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 0):

First you just have override `onBackButtonPressed()`

Then from inside there you can perform whatever actions you wish.
If you want to kill you Activity and go back on the previous one on the stack you can just call finish(). There is no need to override it.

Check out this post for more information
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html